# UITableView with headers: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Trying to setup UITableView with section headers and getting this error when running compiler and trying to navigate to the screen:

> [UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fac00fadce0

Is the problem something with selector @"data"? Something else I need to do in order for it to be recognized?

Here's the .h

```
@interface InviteContactsViewController : UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTable;
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}
```

and .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *firstItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3", nil];
    NSDictionary *firstItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:firstItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
    [dataArray addObject:firstItemsArrayDict];

    NSArray *secondItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item 4", @"Item 5", @"Item 6", @"Last Item", nil];
    NSDictionary *secondItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:secondItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
    [dataArray addObject:secondItemsArrayDict];
}

// Tell table view how many sections it can expect to receive
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [dataArray count];
}

// Tell table view how many rows in each section to expect
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Number of rows it should expect should be based on the section
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    return [array count];
}

// Specify section headers
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(section == 0)
        return @"Section 1";
    if(section == 1)
        return @"Section 2";
    else {
        return @"nothing here";
    }
}
```

Comment: You set a generic `UIView` instance instead of the view controller as your table's `dataSource`. Show the code that creates the table view.

Comment: For starters, InviteContactsViewController needs to be set up as a <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: Are you using xibs/storyboards? If yes, you're assigning your dataSource outlet to an instance of `UIView`, whereas you need to be assigning to the `InviteContactsViewController`.

Comment: @jakenberg yes storyboards. You and rmaddy were exactly right - I switched the dataSource outlet to InviteContactsViewController and presto. Also added in "UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>" like hackerinheels suggested. All working now. Thx!